# use class methods in class variable python

Tags: python

How can I use my format_date function for my class variable?

```
class DailyAggregator(Aggregator):
    time_dirty_data = self.format_date(datetime.datetime.now())
    
    @staticmethod
    def format_date(date):
        return date.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `@classmethod` decorator and use with reference `Daily`, like

```
class Daily(Aggregator):

    time_dirty_data = None

    def __init__(self):
        Daily.time_dirty_data = Daily.format_date(datetime.datetime.now())

    @classmethod
    def format_date(cls, date):
        return date.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

print(Daily.time_dirty_data)
d = Daily()
print(Daily.time_dirty_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to instanciate your class.

Like this:

```
daily = Daily()
daily.format_date(your_date)
```

I think it's what you want ?

Comment: your example is not for class variable but instance variable !

Answer (score 0):

You can the method static and use like this:

```
@staticmethod
def format_date(date):
    return date.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)

time_dirty_data = format_date.__func__(datetime.datetime.now())
```